# TreeView containing different types

Tags: java, javafx, hyperlink, treeview

I've backed myself in a bit of a corner by using a `CheckBoxTreeItem`, because I want the functionality it provides (ability to check all children if parent is checked), but my parent has a `Hyperlink` as the graphic, whereas my children have `Strings` as their graphic. Java does not like it when you have a `TreeView` that contains two different types (`CheckBoxTreeItem<Hyperlink>` and `CheckBoxTreeItem<String>`). My options are to create a `TreeView` that accepts a generic type, or to find a way to display `Hyperlinks` as plain text. I've tinkered with the generic type option for a couple of hours, but cannot seem to get it to work. I'm leaning more toward modifying Hyperlinks, but I will be greatful for advice either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to add a `Node` type, you can use the `graphic` property of `TreeItem`.

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(null, new Hyperlink("abc"));
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item2 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Hello World");
    CheckBoxTreeItem<String> item3 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("42");
    item.getChildren().setAll(item2, item3);

    TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>(item);
    treeView.setCellFactory(CheckBoxTreeCell.forTreeView());

    Scene scene = new Scene(treeView);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Alternatively if the `TreeItem` value contains the `Node`, you need to modify the `updateItem` method of `CheckBoxTreeCell` a bit:

```
CheckBoxTreeItem<Object> item = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new Hyperlink("abc"));
CheckBoxTreeItem<Object> item2 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("Hello World");
CheckBoxTreeItem<Object> item3 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>("42");
CheckBoxTreeItem<Object> item4 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new Hyperlink("def"));
item.getChildren().setAll(item2, item3, item4);

TreeView<Object> treeView = new TreeView<>(item);
treeView.setCellFactory(tv -> new CheckBoxTreeCell<Object>() {

    private final HBox graphicWrapper = new HBox();

    {
        graphicWrapper.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        graphicWrapper.getChildren().clear();
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (!empty && (item instanceof Node)) {
            // replace graphic & text
            setText(null);
            graphicWrapper.getChildren().setAll(getGraphic(),  (Node) item);
            setGraphic(graphicWrapper);
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: Went with method number one. Worked like a charm. For those reading, make sure to include the setCellFactory line. Otherwise you get a TreeView of only strings, no CheckBoxes.